# Firebase iOS: Second tap is working properly in login page

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, verification

I decided to make it simply as possible. Somebody can explain me why at first tap my code hitting Path_4 message (bad path), but at second, third, fourth hitting Path_2 and Path3 messages (good path's)? There is some code:

```
// Login

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: userEmail, password: userPassword) { [weak self] authResult, error in
        guard self != nil else { return }
    }

    // Check user if verified

    if ( Auth.auth().currentUser != nil ) {
        Auth.auth().currentUser!.reload(completion: { (error) in

            if let error = error {
                self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "1", alertMessage: "Path_1");
                print(error)
            } else {
                if Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified {
                    self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "2", alertMessage: "Path_2");
                } else {
                    //TODO Verification page
                    self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "3", alertMessage: "Path_3");
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "4", alertMessage: "Path_4");
    }
```

Comment: Signing in takes time, so it's possible that `Auth.auth().currentUser` is still `nil` briefly after `Auth.auth().signIn` has completed. If you can't deal with that delay, make sure you to put your code in the completion handler for `signIn`, where `authResult.user` is guaranteed to be non-nil on a successful sign-in.

Comment: U mean i need to make some delay or pause? How i can know how long it takes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i tried something like that, but i think it not a finest way to do this:

```
   // Login

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: userEmail, password: userPassword) { [weak self] authResult, error in
        guard self != nil else { return }
    }

    // Check user if verified

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) { // Change `2.0` to the desired number of seconds.
       if ( Auth.auth().currentUser != nil ) {
           Auth.auth().currentUser!.reload(completion: { (error) in

               if let error = error {
                   self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "1", alertMessage: "Path_1");
                   print(error)
               } else {
                   if Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified {
                       self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "2", alertMessage: "Path_2");
                   } else {
                       //TODO Verification page
                       self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "3", alertMessage: "Path_3");
                   }
               }
           })
       } else {
           self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "4", alertMessage: "Path_4");
       }
    }
```

There is something what i can do to pause until sign in action didn't done yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want sign-in to be completed, move that code into the sign-in completion handler:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: userEmail, password: userPassword) { [weak self] authResult, error in
    guard self != nil else { return }

    if authResult.user!.isEmailVerified {
        self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "2", alertMessage: "Path_2");
    } else {
        //TODO Verification page
        self.displayAlertMessage(alertTitle: "3", alertMessage: "Path_3");
    }
}
```

If you also want to respond to passive sign-in state changes (e.g. when the user restarts the app), you can use an additional auth state change listener:

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  if (user != nil) {
    // check if the email is verified, if not reload the token and check again
  }
}
```

The difference with that last piece of code is that an auth state change listener will get called automatically when the auth state changes, instead of you having to call `Auth.auth().currentUser` at the exact right time.